# Jenkins Permission Denied

Tags: jenkins, permissions, jenkins-pipeline, file-permissions, user-permissions

I'm sorry to come here and ask for that but I have read all the internet trying to find a solution but I still have this problem...

I have installed successfully (let's start when I still had hope) jenkins to use it in our continous integration flow.

I tried to start with a simple example like this one :

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But each time I start it, I have this error :

```
sh: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test@tmp/durable-f70a79f3/script.sh: Permission denied
```

The problem is that user jenkins (service and the master node are running as Jenkins) have all the permissions on this repository. I tried to give group and others permissions to read and execute too but it doesn't change anything.

```
[centos@jenkins workspace]$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Dec  8 18:35 Test
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Dec 11 16:40 Test@tmp
```

We are launching jenkins with those parameters :

```
 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/jenkins/tmp
```

and on a /jenkins url. Other than that, I don't see what could be the cause of the problem...

edit : Mounted volumes with noexec

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var_lv on /var type ext4 (rw,nodev,noexec,relatime,nobarrier,data=ordered)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: what do you have in `Test@tmp` ? try to change the permission only to your `script.sh`. Something like: `chmod 755 ${WORKSPACE}/Test@tmp/**/*.sh`

Comment: Can the agents possibly have `noexec` on the volumes (see https://superuser.com/questions/99635/cant-execute-a-script-on-a-mounted-external-drive)?

Comment: @Edwin : I don't have any script in it. I think it's jenkins which creates a .sh in the durable repository and try to execute it.

Comment: have you looked in your `pom.xml` maybe you are doing something with maven at that point

Comment: @mkobit : The problem is that the only mounted volume is on /var/lib/jenkins/tmp. It's not on /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/... and even the mount options don't show noexec : /dev/vdb on /var/lib/jenkins/tmp type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered). Am I watching the wrong mounted volume ? p.s : I have added mounted volumes with noexec in the original post.

Comment: @Edwin : The maven is the one coming from jenkins pipeline examples. It only starts "mvn -B -DskipTests clean package"

Comment: @mkobit : I just saw that /var was mounted with no exec... I didn't thought all files in /var wouldn't be allowed to be executed. I thought it was only in the repository at first but it seems a great lead, I'll keep updated when I find a solution to change it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed the /var with noexec... I didn't thought all /var was in noexec. I read 10 times this line without even trying to change it... Thank you for your help

Solution :
Like I said in comments, it was this line :

`/dev/mapper/rootvg-var_lv on **/var** type ext4 (rw,nodev,**noexec**,relatime,nobarrier,data=ordered)`

So I used `sudo mount -o remount,exec /var` and it's working fine now.

Comment: Hah, glad I could point you in the right direction! It might be helpful to leave some of the steps you did to determine this so that others don't run into it as well.