# jenkins Permission denied node

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

These are the logs of my jenkins execution:

```
> Step 1/2 : FROM tomcat:9.0.4-jre8-alpine
 ---> 631138bc037d
Step 2/2 : COPY /Fatcat-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/fatcat.war
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 700d13ec5fb5
Successfully built 700d13ec5fb5
> 
> [Pipeline] dockerFingerprintFrom
> 
> [Pipeline] }
> 
> [Pipeline] // stage
> 
> [Pipeline] sh
> 
> [unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA]
> Running shell script
> 
>     + docker inspect -f . 3bf1d418c6b61a03e2f2abe9d37b4c5e759e0b0a
> 
> . [Pipeline] withDockerContainer Jenkins does not seem to be running
> inside a container
> 
>     $ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /data/jenkins_ws/unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA
> -v /data/jenkins_ws/unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA:/data/jenkins_ws/unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA:rw,z
> -v /data/jenkins_ws/unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA@tmp:/data/jenkins_ws/unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA@tmp:rw,z
> -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** 3bf1d418c6b61a03e2f2abe9d37b4c5e759e0b0a cat
>     $ docker top f3826ded71315b33b4d352ac2181035655f73d58a7c998040db36b6d664f1421 -eo
> pid,comm
> 
> [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Test) [Pipeline] sh
> [unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA]
> Running shell script
> + node --version /data/jenkins_ws/unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA@tmp/durable-f0e86b83/script.sh:
> line 1: node: Permission denied [Pipeline] }enter code here [Pipeline]
> // stage [Pipeline] } 
> `$ docker stop --time=1`
> f3826ded71315b33b4d352ac2181035655f73d58a7c998040db36b6d664f1421
> 
>     $ docker rm -f f3826ded71315b33b4d352ac2181035655f73d58a7c998040db36b6d664f1421
> 
> [Pipeline] // withDockerContainer [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // node
> [Pipeline] End of Pipeline ERROR: script returned exit code 127
> Finished: FAILURE
```

**The issue is in this line:**

```
> [unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA] Running shell script
> 
>     + node --version
> 
> > /data/jenkins_ws/unFatCat_master-RSJASSVAHZJXKMANQQZOIIGTV3YC2D2GJS65WJ23OAY3WGXOVRJA@tmp/durable-f0e86b83/script.sh:
> > line 1: node: Permission denied
```

I want to use a local ad-hoc Docker. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7-alpine
FROM tomcat:9.0.4-jre8-alpine

COPY /Fatcat-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/fatcat.war
```

Notice I load the *node:7-alpine* in the Docker and not in the Jenkins configuration

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I installed Nodejs plugin in Jenkins.

These are my questions:

1. Why `node --version` is not executed?
2. why the *permission denied* error is reported?
3. Can the problem be that `node --version` is not executed inside the container?

I already checked the *permission denied* error from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756700/jenkins-permission-denied). However the partition is mounted with exec parameter . So the proposed solution is not valid for me.

[image: In-process script approval window]

Answer (score 0):

Change your Jenkins Declaritive pipeline in below format. Hope you will get the result.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
                image 'maven:3-alpine' 
                image 'node:7-alpine' 
           }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to use the dockerfile that is already in my repository. If I load the image like you suggest `docker {...}` the dockerfile in my repo wont be used

Comment: Hmmn, then better setup the nodejs configuration in jenkins - job , else set the environment variable of nodejs in the same pipeline

Comment: Is nodejs needed in order to be able to execute commands inside the docker container?

Comment: As per my knowledge, It should needed